# Помогите определиться с инструментами для реализации задания

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется административная веб-форма. Логика ее такова. При нажатии на кнопку "Редактировать список работ" должны генерироваться поля для ввода символов по две штуки, а также поле редактирования названия элемента списка. Первое поле будет содержать строку, второе - целочисленное значение. Нажатии на кнопку "Добавить вид работ" должна генерироваться дополнительная пара полей. Кнопка "Удалить автомобиль" удаляет строку из списка в левой части страницы. Пока не размещена кнопка сохранения данных.
Чтобы Вы могли понять уровень моей погруженности в тему: Относительно недавно начал изучать JS. "Пересаживался" на данный язык изучив основы Java, поэтому основы ООП в данном языке я помню. Интересует следующее. На Ваш взгляд, какие технологии требуется мне изучить дабы реализовать указанный функционал, где хранить создаваемые и редактируемые данные? При этом требуется реализация объектов, которые будут иметь в полях у себя коллекции, а также числовые или строковые значения? Дайте, пожалуйста, развернутый совет.

Answer (score 0):

Вы перечислили то, что можно просто на JS написать. И тут вы только о браузере говорите, не ясно куда эти данные пойдут, или останутся пока браузер не закроется. Думаю что вам лучше просто продолжать учить JS и вёрстку и пока не думать об инструментах, а реализовать хоть как-нибудь.
И если хотите хранить данные где-то, можете для начала их в localStorage записывать. Потому что иначе вам придётся с серверной частью разбираться, например с php или node.js.

Comment: Как тут можно перейти в чат для обсуждения?

Comment: Cоветовать `jQuery ` в 2020 году уже не является разумным.

Comment: Коли уже начал я изучать js, мне стоит серверную часть попробовать написать на node.js с подключением БД?

Comment: @MoloF, возможно, только на чистом js по-прежнему выходит больше кода и больше нюансов. И jQuery используется ещё широко, его никто не отменял. Советовать React например тут нельзя.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev я не советовал реакт. Я не вижу целесообразным тащить библиотеку в которой много мусора.

Comment: @MoloF ладно, согласен, тут она не нужна. Просто скрипта хватит.

Comment: @ПавелПетров вы сначала определитесь с самим  приложением, что вы от него хотите, локально сохранять какие-то данные или же держать сервер, который по запросу будет отдавать вам необходимые данные? Опишите то, как вы видите приложение, что вы хотите в нем видеть, измените свой вопрос, а потом можно и подсказать, где хранить данные, какие инструменты использовать и можно уже говорить о решении вашего вопроса.

Comment: @MoloF Предполагается хранение данных в MongoDB, скорее всего потребуется написать серверную часть. ибо с проектом будет работать не один человек, получая данные о каждом элементе списка. Извините за некорректно расписаный вопрос. Серверную часть, по всей видимости, придется писать на node.js(т.к. не могу аргументированно сказать почему). По сути, приложение должно предоставлять конечному пользователю параметры объектов, хранящихся в базе. Указанная веб-форма планируется для управления составом, количеством и качественным содержанием параметров этих объектов.